# Do ninja clans have to keep relations only within the clan to ensure the inheritance of abilities?

Tags: naruto

Are there any references to arranged marriages or forbidden relationships in the history of clans being used to avoid the clan abilities from being lost?

Comment: By "forbidden relationships", do you mean incest? Because that might not be forbidden there, just like it wasn't in European royalty.

Comment: No I mean forbidden like "not allowed by the clan"

Comment: That's actually a very good question. We know that there wasn't such a strict law in the Senju or the Uzumaki, we haven't seen Sasuke's mother's Sharingan, so we can't know if she's a pure-blood Uchiha. We haven't seen Hinata's or Neji's mother either, so we can't tell. Unless someone remembers something that I can't.

Comment: I vaguely recall clans marrying their own clanmates to keep a bloodline limit. But I don't think they were necessarily arranged.

Comment: After the main manga epilogue, we have so many cross clan relationship.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the series, the clans usually do not want their "powers" to fall into someone else's hand. As these could be used for research against this power or getting even greater power for the clan that obtains it. Therefore they try to keep relations within clans. Then again  relationships with different clans do exist. Naruto's parents would be a good example for this  as [Minato Namikaze](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Minato_Namikaze) married himself into the Uzumaki clan with [Kushina Uzumaki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kushina_Uzumaki)

> Membership in a clan is usually determined by blood relations and
>   genetics, which is vital in the usage of Kekkei Genkai and secret
>   techniques. These attributes and abilities made many clans feared and
>   renowned throughout many villages. While clans may be composed of many
>   individuals and extended families, many clans mentioned and seen in
>   the series were somewhat limited to a nuclear family. [Wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Clans)

Also this part of the wiki states that family's (clans) can be composed of many families.

As for forbidden relationships, yes they existed (not always in a romantic way ) Look at the first Hokage and Madara Uchiha. They were best of friends yet their family's did not accept their friendship. So if I were to guess I would say that there is a high probability that there are also forbidden relationships

I couldn't find any specific information about forced marriage´s so far. But if I do find some information on this I'll add it here later.